# RegEx for Matching Saudia (KSA) Vehicle Number Patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

Can someone help me with regex for saudia(KSA) Vehicle registration plates 
Basically i'm unable to write regex for latin as it only accept 17 Arabic letters as following with their following english translation

```
ا |  A  
ب |  B  
ح |  J  
د |  D  
ر |  R  
س |  S  
ص |  X  
ط |  T  
ع |  E  
ق |  G  
ك |  K  
ل |  L  
م |  Z  
ن |  N  
هـ |     H  
و |  U  
ى |  V
```

as user can enter in both english and arabic i don't know how to restrict latin character while i can restrict english alphabets with regex

Saudia(KSA) car number pattern contail three letters and up to four numbers

[image: This is the sample car license number plate]

Comment: Can you clarify a little?  Are you looking to restrict inputs to either Latin or Arabic characters but not both in a way that constitutes a legal pattern (3 Latin or Arabic characters wtih up to 4 corresponding Latin or Arabic characters)?

Comment: exactly i want to restrict user to enter in any of the one language so obviously it won't be combination of both english and arabic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for what I think you're looking for, this will accept up to 4 numbers, but no mix of both types of characters within the number or character blocks (although a user can do Arabic numbers and Saudi characters or Saudi numbers and Latin characters).

```
^[\u0660-\u0669|\d]{1,4}[\u0621-\u064A|\w]{3}
```

Legal entries:

```
٢٤٧٩sdf
1334aif
1234حكهـ
حكهـ٢٤٧٩
123abc
12abc
1abc
```

Illegal Entries:

```
٢1٧2 sكf
alfksjdd
12347844
```

Note that the end of line symbol ($) is omitted as this conflicts with Arabic's directionality.  The beginning of line symbol is fine and is necessary to prevent longer, illegal entries which contain the pattern.

Comment: /^[\u0621-\u064A|A-Z|a-z]{3}[0-9|\u0660 -\u0669]{1,4}$/ 
edited it as \w will even accept numbers as it denotes alphanumeric representation.
other than that i think your answer helped me solve my problem

Comment: Good catch. I had that originally but killed it accidentally in editing it to be cleaner.  I added the or's back for consistency.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

According to given image example and

> Saudia(KSA) car number pattern contain three letters and up to four numbers

You could do it simply, like this:

```
\d{1,4}[A-Z]{3}
```

Explanation:

`\d{1,4}` -> means between 1 and 4 digits

`[A-Z]{3}` -> means 3 upper case letters

**But** if you need to include arabic letters as well, then you should use their  unicode specific code points, which you can find here [Unicode for Arabic letters](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf).

Unfortunately I don't know arabic, so I can't test it more than just copy-pasting some of letters you gave.

But theoretically it would be something like this:

```
\d{1,4}[A-Z\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]{3}
```

Explanation:

`\d{1,4}`  -> means between 1 and 4 digits

`[A-Z\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]{3}` -> means 3 unicode characters with code between 0600 and 06FF (according to attached table)

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example that restricts you to the letters A, B and C. You can replace with the specific list of letters:

```
\d{4}[ABCD]{3}
```